# Magento ERP Issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, erp

Using Magento 1.8. Am having erp issues and hoping anyone can point me in the right direction. 
The ERP is through boostmyshop. Have opened a ticket but not getting any help.

The issue:

1. The products in the catalog and not updating in the ERP order preparation
2. Products that are in catalog are in stock, but showing as out of stock. Have to go in and manually refresh each product. It's cumbersome with 20k products. 
   So now any orders that run through are all showing as "stockless"

This might be a separate issue:

3. Orders scanned in with barcode/mobile device are not updating site. Have to manually complete orders

Have checked cron jobs. They are running at 2min intervals. No other erros showing up in exception log regarding this.

Comment: You are using 3rd party ERP integration, so one can only guess what's going on. You should check it with their support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. More relevant to  https://magento.stackexchange.com/